# Unable to update JButton in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, repaint, actionevent

I am trying to build a **TicTacToe game** in **Java** and using **Swing** for GUI. As I doesn't know much Swing, I am using **JButton** for creating tiles. Initially all the tiles are blank.
Now, when a user clicks on an empty tile i.e. an empty button, I want to put a **"X"** or **"O"** depicting image on that button. But I'm unable to do that. Any help is appreciated. I already tried things, but not working.

Here is my code:

```
/* Showing only required code */

public void run(){

        /* Creating blank JButtons */
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
             for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
                tile[i][j] = new JButton("");
                tile[i][j].setActionCommand("Tile: (" + String.valueOf(i) + "," +   String.valueOf(i) + ")"); 
                /* tile[i][j] has setActionCommand as "Tile: (i,j)" */

                panel.add(tile[i][j]);
             }
         }
         panel.setBounds(140, 170, 300, 300);
         add(panel);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setVisible(true);  
 }


 /* HERE LIES THE MAIN PROBLEM AS BUTTONS ARE NOT UPDATED AS EXPECTED*/

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // when lefttop corner tile is clicked
     if("Tile: (0,0)".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
         if(tileDone[0][0] == false){ // checking if its still empty
             if(currentPlayer.equals("X")){ // checking if current player is "X"
                tile[0][0] = new JButton(new ImageIcon("/home/kaustubh/Desktop /java/TicTacToe/X.png"));
                 panel.add(tile[0][0]);
                 panel.repaint();
                 this.repaint();
                 System.err.println();
             }
             else{
                tile[0][0] = new JButton(new ImageIcon("/home/kaustubh/Desktop/java/TicTacToe/O.png"));
                panel.add(tile[0][0]);
                panel.repaint();
                this.repaint();
                System.err.println();
            }
            tileDone[0][0] = false;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why you are adding the button again in `actionPerformed()`.  If you plan to add the button again, you first need to remove the old one.  Instead, you probably mean to just update the icon.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // when lefttop corner tile is clicked
     if("Tile: (0,0)".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
         if(tileDone[0][0] == false){ // checking if its still empty
             if(currentPlayer.equals("X")){ // checking if current player is "X"

                // here...
                tile[0][0].setIcon(new ImageIcon("/home/kaustubh/Desktop /java/TicTacToe/X.png"));
                //panel.add(tile[0][0]);  // remove this

                 panel.repaint();
                 this.repaint();
                 System.err.println();
             }
```